# Error al tratar de usar proyecto en codeigniter en otro equipo

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en codeigniter en mi equipo, el cual funciona muy bien, pero al momento de pasar el proyecto en otro equipo, con la misma versión de xampp no funciona, al principio me presento un error con las session, al quitar la session se corrigio, pero ahora no me carga ninguna vista, me dice el objeto no asido localizado.

Ya verifique los nombres de los archivos que son la principal causa de este error, pero aun así nada.

Este es el error que se me presenta al tratar de montar el proyecto:

[image: Este error es el que se presenta cuando instalo el proyecto]

Al eliminar la session, del config se presenta este otro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al eliminar la condición que me verifica la session en la vista me carga el estilo y todo, pero al momento de acceder a otra ruta me sale esto, las rutas están establecida de acuerdo al servidor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad eso me tiene muy frustrado, ya que es la primera ves que me pasa, estoy utilizando xampp en mi pc con versión de php 7.1 y en el otro equipo el mismo xampp con la misma configuración, alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar esto, lo probé en un servidor gratuito y funciona de lo mas de lindo, pero la intención es presentarlo en local ya que se tiene previsto que el dia de la presentación no se tendrá una conexión optima.
Por cierto, la versión del codeigniter que se esta utilizando en la versión 3,

Comment: Hola, el problema tal vez pueda ser por el .htaccess, los ordenadores en los que estas probando tu proyecto ¿son ambos windows? en linux el archivo .htaccess se configura diferente

Comment: Si los ordenadores son en windows, y si e tenido en cuenta el.htaccess pero parece que todo está bie bien

Comment: bueno, el error que te aparece me ha pasado alguna vez, no se por que, algo que me funcionaba era cambiarle el nombre al controlador.

Comment: si eso mismo pensé, pero me e asegurado que todos los controladores empiecen por la primer en mayúscula, tanto el nombre como la instancia, ya que por lo general ese error sale es por eso, por los nombre, aun asi en cambiado el nombre de todo pero nada

Comment: Que tienes en tu archivo autoload.php?

Comment: Ya configuraste el archivo `httpd.conf` y activaste el modulo `rewrite` para que te acepte el `.htaccess`?